# UiPath: System.NotSupportedException occurs when trying to merge: “Specified method is not supported.”

Tags: git, git-merge, uipath, uipath-studio

I’m currently running into an exception when trying to merge master into a feature-branch using UiPath Studio.
I’m using UiPath Studio version 2019.10.1 Enterprise on a 64-Bit Windows 10 machine and .NET 4.7.2+.

What could have caused that exception? Any feedback would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here’s the call-stack:

```
Error: System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
   at UiPath.Studio.Plugin.Git.Services.UI.ConflictsUiService.<SolveCurrentStep>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at UiPath.Studio.Plugin.Git.Services.UI.ConflictsUiService.<SolveMergeConflicts>d__20.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at UiPath.Studio.Plugin.Git.Services.UI.ConflictsUiService.<SolveConflicts>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at UiPath.Studio.Plugin.Git.Services.UI.MergeUiService.<Merge>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at UiPath.Studio.Plugin.Git.Services.UI.ManageBranchesService.<Merge>d__29.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at UiPath.Studio.Plugin.Git.Services.UI.ManageBranchesService.<ExecuteSelectedAction>d__27.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at UiPath.Studio.Plugin.Git.Services.UI.ManageBranchesService.<ManageBranchesCommandExecute>d__24.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at UiPath.Studio.Plugin.Git.Services.UI.ManageBranchesService.<<get_ManageBranchesCommand>b__21_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at UiPath.Studio.Shared.MVVM.Commands.TaskCommand`3.<Execute>d__32.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_0(Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler), HResult -2146233067
```

Comment: Well, I can definitely say that this has nothing to do with *Git* (nor with Git's merge).

Comment: Are you able to try merging using GIT on its own. eg close UiPath and then use either a git GUI or the Command Line Tools. I have found that in some versions of UiPath the version control features are a little unreliable.

Comment: @torek I totally aggree. The reason why i added the tags is because it occurs when doing a merge-attempt.

Comment: @Conor Merging XAML manually is surely an option, but it's a huge pain. We wanted to avoid resolving merge-conflicts that way, making use of UiPath's built in graphical diff. I wouldn't be surprised if there's a bug in the software though. As you said, I can confirm that UiPath sometimes still seems to be buggy.

Comment: Definitely, I think every bug we've Identified (there have been a few) we've been told it will be resolved in the next release/version (which generally has been the case). If you have an enterprise licence with UiPath can you raise a ticket with there technical support. We've done this a couple of times and they are really helpful and responsive.